# how to render primefaces dynaform with ui-repeat,p:datalist

Tags: jsf, primefaces, uirepeat, primefaces-extensions

I'm trying to create multiple dynaforms in my page which will repeat multiple times by clicking button.

To do this i've used ui-repeat but this is not displaying any dynaform at all.As an alternative solution i have used primefaces datalist(or datatable) they are able to repeat the dynaforms. But here in this solution i'm facing another problem with pe:timepicker, that is if i change value in one time picker that effect all the time pickers in repeated dynaforms.

Is there any solution for repeating dynaforms in ui-repeat. How to isolate the timepicker value change specific to dynaform.

I am using JSF2.1.24,primefaces 4.0-snapshot and primefaces-extention-1.0.0.RC1.

Answer (score 1):

ui:repeat was always buggy. And yes, DynaForm works within PrimeFaces data iteration components. How do you change value in pe:timepicker? There are some tricks for DynaForm. See e.g. [this one](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/dynaform/containerClientId.jsf).

I would suggest you ask in our [sub-forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewforum.php?f=14&sid=d345e017748b28aa6f80f67f369f9a3c) for more information.

Please also use the last final releases 4.0.0 and 1.0.0 respectively.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for the reply. I have posted the same question in the forum. But i have continued my work as i said above by changing the pe source code by seeing [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=34263) link its working fine for me. But with this solution also i'm having the problem that  if i add new dynaform to the data list i'm able to change its values but after adding another dynaform i'm unable to change the value of previous dynaform(changed values are not effecting).